# How to Config My Php MVC In My Cpanel Hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

I am trying to create a blog with php MVC. When I run it on my computer's localhost, the blog can work as it should, but when I try to put it into my cpanel hosting, I just get a blank display.

I've been looking for additional information to solve this problem, many say it has something to do with my .htaccess, but I've tried everything they suggest, and it just does not work.

`.htaccess` that I have like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     # Prevent Indexing
     Options + FollowSymLinks -Indexes
     Options -Indexes


     # Handle Front Controller
     RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
     RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
     RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Index.php [QSA, L]

</ IfModule>
```

Do I need to change it in my hosting cpanel?

How to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check your server's log files... also, add the following in your index file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` Also, make sure the following line in your `php.ini` file is as on: `display_errors = on`

Comment: thanks for your respond. I will try